# Android: Delete item from Listview that was populated using Parse in Custom Adapter

Tags: android, android-listview, parse-platform, delete-row, parseexception

I am trying to delete an item in parse.com using a button in my listview. The listview is populated using a custom adapter class and that is where I will be executing the onClick to delete it. Any help would be great!

UPDATE: Basically I would like delete the module where moduleCode is equal to the position's moduleCode

This is the part of the adapter that I am trying to get to work but the error I get back from ParseException e is: `04-09 19:33:05.408  10425-10425/com.yupo.dominic.yupo E/Error﹕ java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid type for ParseObject: class com.yupo.dominic.yupo.Module`

```
Button moduleDeleteButton = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.moduleDeleteButton);

    moduleDeleteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>("Module");
            query.whereEqualTo("objectId", getItem(position));
            query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
                public void done(List<ParseObject> module, ParseException e) {
                    if (e == null) {
                        // iterate over all messages and delete them
                        for(ParseObject delete : module)
                        {
                            delete.deleteInBackground();
                        }
                    } else {
                        Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                    }
                }
            });
            Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

This is the full adapter:

```
package com.yupo.dominic.yupo;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.parse.FindCallback;
import com.parse.ParseException;
import com.parse.ParseObject;
import com.parse.ParseQuery;

public class CustomListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    // Declare Variables
    Context mContext;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    private List<Module> moduleList = null;
    private ArrayList<Module> arraylist;

    public CustomListViewAdapter(Context context,List<Module> moduleList) {
        mContext = context;
        this.moduleList = moduleList;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        this.arraylist = new ArrayList<Module>();
        this.arraylist.addAll(moduleList);
    }

    public class ViewHolder {
        TextView moduleCode;
        TextView moduleName;
        TextView moduleUni;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return moduleList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Module getItem(int position) {
        return moduleList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder holder;
        if (view == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.module_list_item, null);
            // Locate the TextViews in listview_item.xml
            holder.moduleCode = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.moduleCodeTextView);
            holder.moduleName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.moduleNameTextView);
            holder.moduleUni = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.moduleUniTextView);
            view.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }
        // Set the results into TextViews
        holder.moduleCode.setText(moduleList.get(position).getModuleCode());
        holder.moduleName.setText(moduleList.get(position).getModuleName());
        holder.moduleUni.setText(moduleList.get(position).getModuleUni());

        // Listen for ListView Item Click
        Button moduleDeleteButton = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.moduleDeleteButton);

        moduleDeleteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>("Module");
                query.whereEqualTo("objectId", getItem(position));
                query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
                    public void done(List<ParseObject> module, ParseException e) {
                        if (e == null) {
                            // iterate over all messages and delete them
                            for(ParseObject delete : module)
                            {
                                delete.deleteInBackground();
                            }
                        } else {
                            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                        }
                    }
                });
                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

        return view;
    }
}
```

Here is the Module class if needed:

```
package com.yupo.dominic.yupo;

public class Module {
    private String moduleName;
    private String moduleCode;
    private String moduleUni;

    public String getModuleName() {
        return moduleName;
    }

    public void setModuleName(String moduleName) {
        this.moduleName = moduleName;
    }

    public String getModuleCode() {
        return moduleCode;
    }

    public void setModuleCode(String moduleCode) {
        this.moduleCode = moduleCode;
    }

    public String getModuleUni() {
        return moduleUni;
    }

    public void setModuleUni(String moduleUni) {
        this.moduleUni = moduleUni;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure where your problem is coming from, but you should practice using your on click listeners outside of your `Adapter` but rather use it within the class that consumes it for the `ListView`

Comment: Its been a while since I used parse, but I think your problem is your query. You are calling `findInBackground()` and the callback provides a `List<ParseObject>`. But your error is saying `incorrect type for class com.yupo.dominic.yupo.Module`. So it sounds like to me, your are querying expecting a list or parse objects, but rather you get a single object: `com.yupo.dominic.yupo.Module`.

Comment: @ElliotM Could you possibly provide an example of this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to work this out. I simply changed `query.whereEqualTo("objectId", getItem(position));`

to

```
query.whereEqualTo("moduleCode", getItem(position).getModuleCode());
```

Not exactly what I wanted but it works :)